# Guarantees about atomic pointer assignment

Tags: c++, atomic

Is there any guarantee that the assignment of a pointer variable is atomic?

```
struct S {char a; int* p;};
S * p1 = new S;
S * p2 = new S;

p1 = p2;
```

Comment: You mean "assignment". "Affectation" has no meaning in a programming context.

Comment: @SebastianRedl hah, I answered based on code.... dunno what such word means =P

Answer (score 4):

No, that's why C++ has [atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) types.

Comment: can you argument why ?

Comment: @Guillaume07 Why? this is just how it's, there're no guaranties, to have that (and the cost of that, there's a cost for providing atomicity) you have atomics.

Answer (score 2):

In C++03 there are no such guaranties, because the language in not aware of threads. However on Win32 pointer assignment is guaranteed to be atomic.

> Simple reads and writes to properly-aligned 32-bit variables are
>   atomic operations. In other words, you will not end up with only one
>   portion of the variable updated; all bits are updated in an atomic
>   fashion. However, access is not guaranteed to be synchronized. If two
>   threads are reading and writing from the same variable, you cannot
>   determine if one thread will perform its read operation before the
>   other performs its write operation.
>
> Simple reads and writes to
>   properly aligned 64-bit variables are atomic on 64-bit Windows. Reads
>   and writes to 64-bit values are not guaranteed to be atomic on 32-bit
>   Windows. Reads and writes to variables of other sizes are not
>   guaranteed to be atomic on any platform.

In C++11 there are no such guarantees either, unless std::atomic is used.